# Implement find(), save() ActiveRecord methods for ActiveMerchant CreditCard object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, credit-card, activemerchant

What's the best way to implement ActiveRecord's `find()` and `save()` methods for an ActiveMerchant ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard object in a Ruby on Rails application?

I'd like my credit card objects to inherit from ActiveRecord and ActiveMerchant.

*Caveat: I understand that saving credit card information to a database is always considered a bad idea, and that it's preferable to use a gateway that facilitates card storage for you. Presume that it's necessary and that suitable security standards are being met (PCI DSS, filesystem and database encryption, network separation etc).*

Answer (score 1):

I've created a standard Rails ActiveRecord model using the following:

```
./script/generate model CreditCard first_name:string last_name:string number:string month:integer year:integer type:string start_month:integer start_year:integer issue_number:string
```

This matches the ActiveRecord definition of a credit card.

Also, ActiveMerchant provides `ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCardMethods` which, to quote the ActiveMerchant development team are:

> *Convenience methods that can be included into a custom Credit Card object, such as an ActiveRecord based Credit Card object.*

I've included `ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCardMethods` in my credit card model, and will translate the validations to ensure my definition of a credit card matches ActiveMerchant's.